# JetBrains Rider - prevent debug from stopping on exception

Tags: debugging, exception, rider

I have some **handled** `System.Net.WebException`s in my code. When I try to debug the application, Rider always stops on these exceptions, but I want to skip them and go to the breakpoint set in the source code file. I tried different settings for `Any exception` and `System.Net.WebException` breakpoints. One of my versions of the breakpoint exceptions settings is on screenshot.

Rider version - 2017.3

[image: Breakpoints settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need update to Rider and everything will be fine. Tested on `Rider EAP 2018.1`.